# opengts error (/gprmc/Data) is not available

Tags: java, tomcat, gps, tracking

I am trying to make a test connection between gps2opengts andriod aplication and my opengts server. But the following erorr comes every time. I have the following parameters in my server:

Group: demo
User: admin
and no password.

May be file *gprmc* should be configured by *webapp.conf* . I uncomment above fields in webapp.conf , but again  the same error. Please help to fix this problem.

...
gprmc.parm.account=acct

gprmc.parm.device=dev
...

[image: Android aplication gps2opengts]

Comment: You should check your gprmc server first by making some dummy data request via browser, the error shown on toast seems your server is not setup well so consider checking your server track.war and make sure tht web.xml file mention servlet mapping with class file

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to connect to the web appplication, this is why you get and HTML message as a reply.
Install the gprmc server and set up the host name on android as 10.100.10.126:8080.
It will eventually hit `http://10.100.10.126:8080/gprmc/Data?acct=demo&dev=test01...`
This is just a demo app. It will not let you change the default device "test01".